# How to change color values in styles.xml programatically?

Tags: android, layout, colors, themes

I have an application in which i get hex color code from a web service and using that I've to set the color accordingly in all the layouts.

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Base_Work" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item android:id="@+id/color_primary" name="colorPrimary">#9B59B6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#8E44AD</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#5b1cd8</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ba78ff</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ba78ff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ba78ff</item>
</style>
```

This is my theme in styles.xml.

I apply

```
  setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Base_Work);
```

to set the theme in my BaseActivity and every activity.

Now this is my **ONE** of the layout widget in which i am using **colorPrimary** to set the color.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Now I want to change the **colorPrimary** of the theme after web service call.

Any help would be appreciated..

I am stuck in for 2 days.

Comment: change the colour by the code at the runtime.

Comment: I cant change it for every layout widget in every activity file buddy. I have more than 100 activities and 1000+ widgets.. I want to get this thing using just one change .. :-)

Comment: what type of app you are developing ? and why you used 100 activities.

Comment: Simple answer: I cant update every widget color at runtime.

Comment: then you carry on with stucking this issue.

Comment: Any solution you found ?